# Index showing source code

Tags: php, frontpage

Suddenly the wordpress showing the source code when I click the url address, and I get this

> The code is just the site offline plugin i have so i can set the site offline

So the problem is that doesn't parse the code to html/php but show it as plain source code...

Comment: include your codes, so people can check out what's going on there!

Comment: Please add your code! It is frustrating to try and work from a low quality picture. Simply just copy and paste the code that is giving you the errors. Your pic is useless

Answer (score 2):

The problem was at .htaccess

In the plugin w3 total cache I had enabled the option page cache, disk enache I switch to Disk basic.

Then at the .htaccess it removed this code

```
    # BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
```

and left only with the default ,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my problem was fixed, no problem again at index.php now loading just fine.

Comment: Rather just downvote or add a comment to the answer you are tageting, no need to make such a noise in an answer

Comment: Sorry, but these days the communities of stack are better to criticize rather than try to help.